# Why does cargo build ignore the lock file when lock changed by git?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, lockfile

I'm confused about the behavior of `cargo build` when the lock file changes between builds:

1. Run `cargo clean`
2. Run `cargo build`
3. Change the lock file to a previous version using git
4. Now rerun `cargo build`

In my case, despite the `Cargo.lock` having changed between the two builds, `cargo` doesn't rebuild. It immediately returns successfully. Why is that? What am I doing wrong or is this a bug?

The changes are only in the dependencies, not in the main binaries that are output.

I searched the Rust forum and issues and couldn't find this case.

Comment: Might be because the modification date of the `Cargo.lock` file isn't newer than the `Cargo.toml` after changing the lock file with git, since git overrides the modification date of `Cargo.lock` with the modification date the file had when committed?

Answer (score 0):

This might happen if you use separate `Cargo.lock` files with Cargo's [workspace feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html). So if your project looks like this:

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
├── cli
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
├── core
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── lib.rs
├── gui
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
```

There will be only one `Cargo.lock` file within the root directory. And lock files in the sub directories will be ignored. From the docs:

> A workspace is a set of packages that share the same Cargo.lock and
> output directory.

The resolution is simple. Remove the `Cargo.lock` files from the crates and place one in the root directory of your project.

Answer (score -1):

You have to run with `--locked` flag, from the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-build.html#manifest-options):

> --frozen
> --locked

> Either of these flags requires that the Cargo.lock file is up-to-date. If the lock file is missing, or it needs to be updated,
> Cargo will exit with an error. The --frozen flag also prevents Cargo
> from attempting to access the network to determine if it is
> out-of-date. These may be used in environments where you want to
> assert that the Cargo.lock file is up-to-date (such as a CI build) or
> want to avoid network access.

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. The lock file is still ignored, even though it has changed since the last build. So I seem to have found a bug?

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer, that is weird. how about adding `--offline` to the ecuation? `cargo build --offline --locked`